# Trouble connecting to the internet, strange IP problem

Tags: 12.04, internet, internet-connection

I'm having trouble booting but that's probably a separate question. When I run things like `sudo apt-get update`, I get a massive array of error messages, all of them reading something along the lines of `Failed to fetch <domain and path> Something wicked happened resolving <domain>`. I saw in another post running the command `ifconfig`, I don't see my IP address anywhere in the text that command returns, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to.

Whenever I try to ping something such as `ping google.com` I get `ping: unknown host google.com`. I pinged my IP and got the following:

```
PING <my IP> (<my IP>) 56(84) bytes of data.
From <169.254.*.** IP> icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From <169.254.*.** IP> icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From <169.254.*.** IP> icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
--- <my IP> ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4000ms
pipe 4
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your NIC failed to receive an IP properly from your DHCP server. Check to make sure DHCP is enabled on your router, and that you don't already have a static IP reserved on your router for your device.

From superstition, I don't know if it actually does anything:
It may be best to power cycle your router and machine after connecting to the network.

More about **169.254.0.0** IP addresses [here](http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained/).